# Python Normalization Function: Minimize Value as it Grows

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math

I have this array showing the number of users of some `X` product:

```
users_by_product = [28742, 67514, 3312, 430089, 16125, 11984, 625074, 21800386, 7851, 33,
                    3751, 21659, 99, 67, 84800, 495868, 95100, 2400, 2700, 2800, 3200, 3600]
```

I need to map these values to a range from 0 to 10, so I'm currently doing this:

```
for product_users in users_by_product:
    visitors_scaled = (10*(product_users - np.min(users_by_product))/np.ptp(users_by_product)).astype(int)
```

Where `product_users` is `users_by_product[i]`. With an output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The issue is that this variable returns all zeros except a 10 for one product (because that product has lots of users), here is a plot of `users_by_product`.

[image]

As you can see there is one product with lots of users, that is obtaining 10 score and the rest only zeros, my question is if there is a way of minimizing the impact of this value in the function as it increases, so that the huge value doesn't affect too much to the end result and I the others can get some value different than zero while maintaing the initial relationship.

Comment: Compress the range of the data by working with their log. Your [mre] should show any imports needed. What is `product_users` ... `NameError: name 'product_users' is not defined`

Comment: @wwii `product_users` is each value of `users_by_product`. So the line of code that returns the range from 0 to 10 should be call for each `product_users` in `users_by_product`.

Comment: @wwii I've already updated the question with the exact code to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to the calculation compress the range of the data by taking its log.

```
import math
import numpy as np
users_by_product = [28742, 67514, 3312, 430089, 16125, 11984, 625074, 21800386, 7851, 33,
                    3751, 21659, 99, 67, 84800, 495868, 95100, 2400, 2700, 2800, 3200, 3600]

users_by_product = [math.log(n) for n in users_by_product]
for product_users in users_by_product:
    visitors_scaled = (10*(product_users - np.min(users_by_product))/np.ptp(users_by_product)).astype(int)
    print(visitors_scaled,end=', ')
```

---

```
>>> 
5, 5, 3, 7, 4, 4, 7, 10, 4, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
```

Comment: Also note that for calculating the log you could just use `np.log(users_by_product)`

Comment: .. You started with a Python list so I chose the the list comprehension to not change your process too much.